# mySQL Query Optimization (RANGE)

Tags: mysql

Ok so the query is dead simple. This is the table it is stored in:

```
CREATE TABLE `ips` (
  `ip` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_start` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_end` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `IP` (`ip`),
  KEY `IP_RANGE_END` (`ip_end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This table is filled with either singular IPs (in the IP column) or an IP Range (ip_start to ip_end).

Below is the function I am using:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `in_adometry`(in_ip VARCHAR(30)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

SET @ip = 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @ip FROM ips WHERE (INET_ATON(in_ip) BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end) OR  ip = INET_ATON(in_ip) LIMIT 1;

IF @ip > 0  THEN
    RETURN 1;
END IF;

RETURN 0;
END
```

I am currently hosting this on Amazon's RDS (medium size), and I can't get any more then 800 queries a second before the CPU hits over 100%. There is NOTHING else in this RDS but this one table. There are 1.1 million singular IPs, followed by about 3,000 IP Ranges (over 20 million IPs all together). What can I do to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

Doing the `count(*)` is probably unnecessary.  Try this:

```
BEGIN
IF exists (SELECT 1
           FROM ips
           WHERE INET_ATON(in_ip) BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end OR ip = INET_ATON(in_ip)
          )
THEN
    RETURN 1;
END IF;

RETURN 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for slow query is (from MySQL documentation):

> With tables that use the MEMORY storage engine, if you run queries that examine ranges of values (using operators such as >, <=, or BETWEEN on the indexed columns), create the index with the USING BTREE clause. The default (USING HASH) is fast for retrieving individual rows with an equality operator (= or <=>), but is much slower (requiring a full table scan) to examine a range of column values. A MEMORY table created with the USING BTREE clause is still fast for equality comparisons, so use that clause for your MEMORY tables that handle a variety of queries.

Changing the index type can speed up your query dramatically. Please read [Avoid Full Table Scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) for more information.

Comment: Does this correlate to the fact that I am using an INNODB table though?

Comment: Run EXPLAIN on your. That will clarify whether your query is doing full table scan.

Comment: Nope no full table scan, doing a union_join though on my two indexes.